# AutoHotKey: read of two underscore keys

Tags: text, autohotkey, instant

One part of my AutoHotKey script should recognize if `__` is typed.

Following the [AutoHotKey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/HotkeyFeatures.htm#pass-through), I've tried:

```
~__::
  tooltip,hi world
return
```

and got this error:

```
Line Text: ~__::
Error: Invalid hotkey.
```

this shows no errors, but works only for one underscore:

```
~_::
  tooltip,hi world
return
```

this shows no errors, but it just clears the __:

```
:*:__:: 
  tooltip,hi world
return
```

this shows error `Error: Invalid hotkey.`:

```
~:*:__:: 
  tooltip,hi world
return
```

this shows no errors, but does nothing (Doku: [Executehotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#X)) :

```
:X:~__::
  tooltip,hi world
return
```

Comment: this shows no error. its deletes first the `__` and then writes it again. but it destrois other functionalites of my script. therefore its not useful for me:

    :*:__::
     send,__
     tooltip,hi
    return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 4 potential solutions. I have left one working, comment out/uncomment hotkey labels by adding/removing leading semicolons as appropriate.

The 2 blocks of code are functionally equivalent, and for the 2 alternatives, within each block, `b0` prevents automatic backspacing, i.e. the underscores that you typed are not deleted.

```
;:*?:__:: ;deletes the underscores
:b0*?:__:: ;does not delete the underscores
SoundBeep
return

;note: the X option requires AHK v1.1.28+
;:X*?:__::SoundBeep ;deletes the underscores
;:Xb0*?:__::SoundBeep ;does not delete the underscores
```

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotKey recognize if `__` is typed:

```
countUnderscore :=0
~_::
     countUnderscore++
     if(countUnderscore == 2){
        tooltip, %countUnderscore% = countUnderscore
        countUnderscore := 0
      }
return
```